# GPU not detected by tensorflow in VSCode

Tags: tensorflow, visual-studio-code, gpu, nvidia

Laptop : ROG

GPU : NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 Ti

Python : Ananconda 3 with Python 3.7

Tensorflow 2.3 installed from anaconda env

CUDA Toolkit : 10.1

cuDNN : 7.6

So, I already try basically everything like install proper CUDA Tool Kit, cuDNN, Microsoft Studio, NVIDIA Driver, and anything else, but my VSCODE still not detect my GPU.

i try to print my GPU like this in VSCODE:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
```

It shows nothing and when I check available physical it only shows my CPU.

Anyone have any idea with what happened to my vscode/laptop?